# 2 данные между двумя контроллерами SWIFT

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview, делегаты

Есть два контроллера, на первом такие элементы: две кнопки и тэйблвью, при нажатии добавить - открывается второй контроллер, там вводится информация на трех текстфилдах и после нажатия кнопки "окей" мне надо передавать информацию к классу первого контроллера и чтобы в тэйблвю в этот момент добавлялся cell, с этой же инфой. Где такой код найти для ознакомления?

Comment: думаю этот урок подойдет. https://medium.com/@mayooresan/passing-data-between-viewcontrollers-via-delegate-protocols-4ecde4b167de

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов спасибо, по большей части решает мои проблемы